# "Error (active) E1696 cannot open source file "stdafx.h"--

Tags: c++

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFmiM.png)

i am trying to solve this Hanoi Tower in c++. am pretty sure the syntax is good,i have tried finding a solution to no avail, i just need some help fixing the error.

Comment: Please post code enclosed by ``` and ```, not images! (Note, those are tildes)

Comment: Off-topic: @alteredinstance, those are called backticks, backquotes, or grave accent. A tilde is ~

Comment: The compiler is telling you that `stdafx.h` is not in any of the folders that are in your include search path.

Comment: @ChrisMM Thanks, I always accidentally call them tildes because theyre on the tilde key on my keyboard. An important distinction haha

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Project > (ProjectName)Properties > C/C++ > Precompiled Headers` and set `Precompiled Header` to `Not Using Precompiled Headers`.

Then remove the line in your code that says:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

And next time when you make a new project, just use a blank template without precompiled headers. :)

(Also, post ***code***, not a *picture* of code)